# Some commands don't come out in the pdf - TeXmaker

Tags: titles, texmaker

I'm just starting to learn how to use the program and watching tutorials online, at the moment I'm using TexMaker. Everything seems to be going just fine however when I try to use the commands `\title`, `\author`, and `\date`, they become highlighted red as if the program acknowledges them as a command. However when I compile the code into a PDF everything else appears just not those three.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you add `\maketitle` at the start of the document?

Comment: Did you add something after them, too e.g. `\title{Great title}` or `\author{Me}`?

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a minimal example of your code to solve the problem. The red color in TexMaker indicates a syntax error. Here is an example short document to help you start with these commands in your LaTex document.

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % for random text
\begin{document}

\title{My Title}
\author{AboAmmar}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

%
\lipsum*[1-2]
\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

And the output is as follows:

[image]

You can start with [a not so short introduction to latex](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf)
to learn more.

Comment: sorry i didn't really think of putting an example in, and for some reason your code works perfectly but if i try to change what is inside the \title{-} brackets it stops

Comment: Never mind i realize now I was missing the command \maketitle, Thanks alot!